# Diagnosing high CPU usage and strange issues

Tags: windows, memory, ssd, cpu

Totally stumped with an issue that seems to persist across machines.

Symptoms are

- High CPU usage (100% or close to)
- Device manager hangs when opening - it may open after 5-10 minutes
- HP Audio Controls/Flow.exe using multiple gigs of RAM - this isn't always the case and may just be because the PC tends to go long times between reboots, but I don't see this on other HPs.
- PC takes 1 minute to boot to Windows (SSD, out of box it takes 10 seconds)

I have been unable to narrow down what's causing these problems. Going down the rabbit hole with process explorer etc takes me to a different answer each time.

I've tried

- Reinstalled Windows from image 2 (used elsewhere with no issues)
- Reinstalled Windows from image 2 on the same model of known-good PC
- Reinstalled Windows from image 2 in a different model of PC.

Pc models are Elitedesk 800 G3 Mini and 800 G5 SFF, i5, 8gb/16gb RAM. Original issue was with image 1, persists with image 2. Haven't tried a flat Windows install yet, but these images are fine elsewhere.

Installed software is Office, Acrobat, Gemalto Card reader software, Duo security. Removed Gemalto and no change. All drivers up to date.

Unchanged are monitors, cables, physical location.

Really stumped how the issue presents itself again on different installs and different machines. During set up, there is no apparent issue. Used off and on myself to test before providing and it never seems to have a problem until provided to user. Users log in with AD account.

Are there any suggestions on how to narrow down this issue?

Comment: You should try a fully stock Windows 10 install (I assume you are on windows 10?) before troubleshooting further. There may be a problem with the image, and compatibility with hardware.

Comment: My confusion comes from the fact that the same image is fine with no issues on other machines, including those of the same model. I will be trying this although it is of course very inconvenient..! It is Windows 10, yes..

Comment: What is the workload on the machines? Any non-vanilla software installed? Fully updated? Connected to a net, possible malicious (or simply terminally clueless) users? Take a peek at [the definite guide to question asking](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: Workload is light - office. Non vanilla software as stated. Connected to a company network which is heavily restricted and locked down - lots of protections in place ie users can't download exes, Internet is through a proxy etc etc.